# SQL for absolute dummies

Tags: php, sql

I am a complete and utter dummy when it comes to any kind of server-based scripting, it's so bad that I can't even seem to connect to my server's database. SQL/PHP tutorials say that I should use:

```
mysql_connect($database, $user,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
```

How do I find out the database's name? Is this something I should ask the administrator?

I know this is a really silly question, but I have spent considerable time searching for an answer online.

Comment: Yes, your administrator should be able to give you all the information you need about the database name, and the username and password to use.

Comment: do **NOT** use `mysql` extension. it is **deprecated**. Use `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: You should not uuse the mysql functions anymore.  Instead, use the mysqli functions or PDO.  More info at http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: I was just following the first tutorial I found. Do any of you have a suggestion for where I can find a good (online) guide to PHP/SQL?

Comment: this type of question is one to ask your host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to make it short: yes - this is something your administrator can give you, as he chose the name when he created the database.

Answer (score 0):

Its depends:

- If your are with a very cheap hoster you get 1 fixed database
  assigned. Sometimes you can choose a name with a a fixed prefix
- If your are with a decent hoster you often can create 5 or
  so databases, and choose your own name. Often there is a prefix to
  the name.
- If you have your own server, are on a vps, or have xamp or lamp installation, your can
  create your own databases, and give your own, logic names to them.

So, pick your choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to this and are looking for some exposure to learning SQL/php programming I highly suggest installing a copy of XAMPP ( http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html ) as it will give you a local installation of MySQL, Apache Web Server and PHP for you to learn on without using production data.

You can also get some high quality learning databases from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html in order to learn from.